# How to increase plot size of corrplot in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot correlation matrix using corrplot library in R. How can i change the width and height of plot. Currently it is small.

This is my code :  `corrplot(mydata.cor, method="number", addCoef.col = 1,number.cex = 0.3, tl.cex = 0.3)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are saving to `png`, but this will work with any file format if you change the output function:

```r
png(filename = "mycorrplot.png", width = 1200, height = 800)
corrplot(mydata.cor, method="number", addCoef.col = 1,number.cex = 0.3, tl.cex = 0.3)
dev.off()
```

Just change the width and height to the right size for you. However, you are plotting a relatively large matrix on one plot, so it might be difficult to make it look good.